# Convert discrete non-UTC date/time parts to a UTC DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, nodatime

When using Noda Time, is there a more direct way to go from a set of discrete non-UTC values (that is to say, separate year, month, day, hour, minute values) to a UTC DateTimeOffset variable? I'm doing the following in a loop and it seems a bit odd to create `LocalDateTime` then apply two different timezones in a row.

```
DateTimeOffset target = 
    new LocalDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
        .InZoneStrictly(dataTimeZone)
        .WithZone(utcTimeZone)
        .ToDateTimeOffset();
```

I realize I'm probably overthinking/micro-optimizing, but since I'm new to Noda Time I'm mostly asking in case there is a way with fewer steps or that is better in some way. (I'm aware `InZoneStrictly` can throw exceptions, this is actually related to a scheduling system, so I definitely don't want invalid or auto-adjusted results.)

Comment: That looks fine to me - if you take "what you've got to start with" (a local date/time and a time zone) and "what you want to end up with" (a DateTimeOffset with an offset of 0, because you want the UTC value) then those transformations seem exactly appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is fine, though you could use `DateTimeZone.Utc` instead of `utcTimeZone`.

Here's another implementation that will give the same results:

```
DateTimeOffset target =
    new LocalDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
        .InZoneStrictly(dataTimeZone)
        .ToInstant()
        .ToDateTimeOffset();
```

You might consider whether you actually *need* `DateTimeOffset` or not.  Unless you're calling to some other API that requires one, you could use an `OffsetDateTime` or just an `Instant` instead.

As for the part about `InZoneStrictly`, consider that a user might pass in a perfectly valid set of date and time values that just happen to be ambiguous within the given time zone because they represent a local time during a backward transition (either for DST or change in standard time).  Do you really want to throw in such cases?

Also, consider that if you have logic that applies a daily recurrence for the same time on multiple days, eventually you could run into an invalid time during the gap of a forward transition (again either for DST or change in standard time).

In Noda Time 2.x, [`InZoneLeniently`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDateTime.html#NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZoneLeniently_NodaTime_DateTimeZone_) was updated to generally do the right thing in such scenarios (first occurrence of ambiguous values, skip ahead for invalid values).  Scheduling was a primary use case in this decision.

Comment: Thanks, I'm converting to `DateTimeOffset` for writing future events to SQL but the rest of the system is `Instant` based. As I understand it, that's an appropriate column type versus serializing an `Instant`. I recently switched away from `InZoneLeniently` but I'll reconsider. The discrete values are config items that must be reevaluated over long periods of time (probably years) to produce new future schedule targets, and it's the sort of system that is resilient to missed invocations so I do think skipping invalid events is reasonable (mostly DST transitions).